# Putting <nav> inline with <header> CSS

Tags: html, css, header, nav

First off, I learned most of what I know about CSS/HTML by using frameworks. I am trying to go back and learn the basics to understand the CSS selectors and inheritance.

I have read on W3C that both  and  are good semantic markup for a header. So what I am trying to do is create a header with a logo floated left and a navigation menu floated right. The problem is my nav menu is sitting right below my header. I want to make this responsive. Here is what I have thus far.

```
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Testing</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a href=""><li>Home</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>About</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Contact</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</header>
```

The CSS is as follows

```
header {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:1rem 5rem;
    background:#cccccc;
    color:#fff;
}
header h1 {
    line-height: 45px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 0; 
}
nav {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float:right;
}

nav  li {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Droid Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #222;
    padding:0 1rem;
}
nav li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
nav > li > a:hover,
nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Laktau5z/)

Comment: What is the actual question? What problem are you facing?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Trying to add a photo now [link]http://www.cantaloupecreative.info/questions/headerissue.JPG

Answer (score 3):

You have to set display to inline for  and . Your updated css will be:

```
  header h1 {
    line-height: 45px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 0;
    display:inline;
}
nav {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float:right;
    display:inline;
}
```

You can also check at: http://jsfiddle.net/2g763j9t/

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
display: inline;
float: left;
```

to the header h1

```
header h1 {
    line-height: 45px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 0; 
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sncb91t8/

This will make the h1 and nav side by side 
I also added a

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

after the nav so the grey background will encompass the h1 and nav

Comment: I wish I could upvote both responses. Perfect. Thank you very much and @j08691

Answer (score 0):

Floating the nav element makes the parent container think it doesn't exist, so it effectively shrinks. To restore the behavior you're after, add `overflow:auto;` to `header`:

```
header {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    max-width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:1rem 5rem;
    background:#cccccc;
    color:#fff;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Laktau5z/1/)**

If you'd like them to align a little better, just move the h1 after the nav ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/c351wfjs/))

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I understand what you are saying. Could you also advise me on how to position the <nav> within the header. I know I can add margin and padding but is there a way to make it equal to the H1 I have in the header? I know this is a little outside the scope of this question but any direction will help.

Comment: Equal to the H1 in what way? Are you referring to the second fiddle example in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

**In Simple Words**

***add below code in index.html***

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**and add below code to your html**

```
<header id="header" style="position: fixed;height: auto; width: 100%; z-index: 9999;" >
<div class="top-bar">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner" >
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll " href="#page-top"> </a>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<b>Ngcourse</b>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" style="height: 64px;" alt="logo"></a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Earning</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Blogs</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
<li  class="active"><a href="#service" > Our Services</a></li>
<li  class="active"><a href="#about1"  >Contact Us </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div> 
</nav> 
</div>
</header>
```